# Write a C program to find whether the given string is Lucky or not

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

A string is said to be lucky if the sum of the ASCII values of the characters in the string is even. The function accepts a pointer to a string and returns an int.
The return value is 1 if the string is lucky and 0 otherwise.

I have tried with the following code, but on execution I am getting some errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int checklucky(char *a);
int main()
{
    int c;
    c=checklucky(char *a);

    if(c==1)
        printf("%s is lucky",a);
    else
        printf("%s is not lucky",a);

    return 0;
}

int checklucky(char *a)
{
    char name[100];
    int sum=0,len,i;
    a=name;

    printf("Enter the input string\n");
    scanf("%s",name);

    len=strlen(name);

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+name[i];
    }

    if(sum%2==0)
        return (1);
    else
        return (0);
}
```

Sample Input and Output 1:

```
Enter the input string
anitha
anitha is not lucky
```

Comment: `but on execution i am getting some errors`.  What errors?  Did you step through with a debugger?

Comment: Declare `name` in `main` and pass it to the function.

Comment: Your question was downvoted because you did not provide sufficient detail as to what the exact problem is (e.g. what errors you were getting).  Even though your question is already answered, you can edit it to improve the quality.  Some people that previously downvoted may undo the downvote, or you may even attract upvotes.  Leave a comment here if you edit your question so that others are notified.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

This line is incorrect and should not compile

```
c=checklucky(char *a);
```

You declared `checklucky` to accept a pointer to the input string, but you are actually gathering that input string within `checklucky`.  Move that part into `main`, then pass in the string.

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    char name[100];
    scanf("%s",name);

    c=checklucky(name);
```

then

```
int checklucky(char *a)
{
    int sum=0,len,i;

    len=strlen(a);
    // etc.  Refer to a rather than name, 
    // or change the method parameter's name to name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Eric J. has already told what is your mistake.

You can take the input string in main() and pass the pointer to it to the called function. There are many ways you can modify your code to get it working.

Below is one way (it tries to keep code similar to the original code)

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 int checklucky( char *);
 int main()
 {
    int c;
    char a[100];
    printf("Input string: ");
    scanf("%s",a);

    c=checklucky(a);

    if(c==1)
        printf("%s is lucky\n",a);
    else
        printf("%s is not lucky\n",a);

    return 0;
}

int checklucky(char *a)
{
    char *name;
    int sum=0,len,i;
    name=a;

    // printf("Enter the input string\n");
    // scanf("%s",name);

    len=strlen(name);

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
       sum=sum+name[i];
   }

   if(sum%2==0)
       return (1);
  else
       return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h> 
int checkLucky(char *a); 
int main() 
{ 
char b[100]; 
int d; 
printf("Enter the input string\n"); 
gets(b); 
d=checkLucky(b); 
if(d==1) 
{ 
printf("%s is lucky\n",b); 
} 
else 
printf("%s is not lucky\n",b); 
return(0); 
} 
int checkLucky(char *a) 
{ 
int sum=0; 
while(*a!='\0') 
{ 
sum+=*a; 
a++; 
} 
if(sum%2==0) 
{ 
return(1); 
} 
else 
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Computation time is less and the memory space consumed is also low as relatively lesser number of variables are used.